# Converting kg to lb in a dataset

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(weight = c(200, 150, 55, 65, 110),
                 unit = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1))
```

1 is pounds
2 is kg

Is there a code that converts only kg weights to pounds?

Answer (score 3):

We can just multiply on the subset of rows where the 'unit' is 2 and assign back

```
i1 <- df$unit == 2
df$weight[i1] <- df$weight[i1] * 2.2
```

---

or it is more compact in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[unit == 2, weight := weight * 2.2]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an indexing solution. Use the `unit` indicator to select from a vector of options for use as a multiplicand for the recorded weight:

```
df <- data.frame(weight = c(200, 150, 55, 65, 110),
                  unit = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1))
 df$true_wt <- df$weight * c(1,2.2)[df$unit]
 df
#--------------
  weight unit true_wt
1    200    1     200
2    150    1     150
3     55    2     121
4     65    2     143
5    110    1     110
```

This is likely to be much more efficient than an `ifelse` approach in situations where the length of the vectors are quite long. You could also assign back to the same `weight` column although I find that dangerous practice. Note that this uses numeric indexing of the options, so it gets applied to all values of `df$weight` and does not need any indexing on the LHS of the assignment. @akrun's code uses logical indexing and therefore needs an indexing operation on the LHS (but looks a bit simpler on the RHS). Either indexing method witll be more efficient than `ifelse` strategies.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [ifelse()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/ifelse) statement. The syntax is `ifelse( condition, value_if_true, value_if_false )`.

```
df$weight_lbs = ifelse( df$unit == 2, df$weight * 2.2, df$weight )
```